# how to send mail from .net?

Tags: .net, email, smtpclient

I want to send email from my .net application. Please tell me the steps for sending email.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SendMailUsingGmailAccount.aspx) tutorial can be helpful to you.
For more search on Google for it. It is **free** to search on it.

Comment: Why don't you just google the answer? Supposing you want the answer in C# you can follow for example msdn [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/)

Comment: Please check the link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Comment: @user601367 It would have helped to tag your question with the language you want to use; or with ".NET" at the very least. Retagging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by exploring  System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient type in .net. This type offers overload method Send.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w4as51.aspx)

---

```
    public static void CreateTestMessage1(string server, int port)
    {
        string to = "jane@contoso.com";
        string from = "ben@contoso.com";
        string subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
        string body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server, port);
        // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
        // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage1(): {0}",
                  ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```